# Retrieving one integer value from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I fetch an integer value from the database?

```
$query = mysql_query('select number from table_name where UNIQUE_ID =SOME_UNIQUE_ID');
```

I am unable to access the integer value using the query above.

Comment: What error did you get? What did you try?

Comment: are you getting some error?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the value i want to access don't show up  The query is returning no value and i am not familiar with php I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have commented, it's unclear what is the problem your are facing.

The `$query` variable you are obtaining is NOT the integer you want but a "query object" (or `False` if the query failed). You have to extract at least a row using (e.g.) `$t=mysql_fetch_array($query)`. The wanted value will be in `$t[0]`.

Keep in mind, anyway, that the result of a query is tipically a string, so you have to extract its integer value using `intval($t[0])`.

Comment: my code is showing error below is my code                                 $src_name = $_GET['source'];      $des_name = $_GET['destination'];                        $src_no_query = mysql_query('SELECT s_no from route201 where s_name =$src_name',$link);
$des_no_query = mysql_query('SELECT s_no from route201 where s_name = $des_name',$link);   $src_int=mysql_fetch_array($src_no_query); $des_int = mysql_fetch_array($des_no_query); echo "<br>$src_int[0] and $des_int[0]<br>";  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given in C:\wamp\www\busmodule\search.php online41

Comment: It seems that mysql_query returned `False` because the query was invalid. Try putting quotes around variables values, like this: `$src_no_query = mysql_query('SELECT s_no from route201 where s_name ="$src_name"',$link);`